# Problem with special characters and os.path.getsize() in Python

Tags: python, windows, character

I'm trying to get the file size of all files in a folder. I've wrote a script that seems to work, and in facts it works until I find some files with special characters, like "š". In thi case, I get this error:

WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: '...Strojni\x9aki...'

> > > > 

(le fichier spécifié est introuvable = The file cannot be found)

The complete word should be "Strojni**š**ki". Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Below, the code as I've wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import enum
from os import path, startfile

# Enum for size units
class SIZE_UNIT(enum.Enum):
   BYTES = 1
   KB = 2
   MB = 3
   GB = 4

def convert_unit(size_in_bytes, unit):
   """ Convert the size from bytes to other units like KB, MB or GB"""
   if unit == SIZE_UNIT.KB:
       return size_in_bytes/1024
   elif unit == SIZE_UNIT.MB:
       return size_in_bytes/(1024*1024)
   elif unit == SIZE_UNIT.GB:
       return size_in_bytes/(1024*1024*1024)
   else:
       return size_in_bytes

def get_file_size(file_name, size_type = SIZE_UNIT.BYTES ):
   """ Get file in size in given unit like KB, MB or GB"""
   size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
#   return size
   return convert_unit(size, size_type)

# start editable vars #
outputfile  = "...\\listfile.txt"   # file to save the results to
folder      = "...\\"       # the folder to inventory
exclude     = ['Thumbs.db','.tmp']  # exclude files containing these strings
pathsep     = "\\" # path seperator ('/' for linux, '\\' for Windows)
# end editable vars #

with open(outputfile, "w") as txtfile:
    j=1
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk(folder):
        if j==1:
            sep = "#############################################" + " START LISTING FILES" + " #############################################\n"
        else:
            sep = "\n \n---------- " + path.split(pathsep)[len(path.split(pathsep))-1] + " ----------\n"
            
        print sep
        txtfile.write("%s\n" % sep)
        print(path)
        txtfile.write(path)
        j=j+1
                
        for fn in sorted(files):
            if not any(x in fn for x in exclude):
                filename = os.path.splitext(fn)[0]
                fileext = os.path.splitext(fn)[1]
                gg = path + "\\" + filename + fileext
                ss = get_file_size(gg, SIZE_UNIT.KB)
                print(ss)
                ss = str(ss)
                sp = ("  " + ss + " KB")
                print ('{:99s} {:5s} {:7s}'.format(filename, fileext, sp))
                txtfile.write('{:99s} {:5s} {:7s}'.format("\n" + filename, fileext, sp))



txtfile.close()
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `pathsep     = "\\" # path seperator ('/' for linux, '\\' for Windows)` better use `os.path.sep`.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! However, it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce... may have to do with the _locale_, or whatever it's called on Windows, or the Python version. (I tried with Python 2.7.18 on Linux.)

Comment: The code needs to be filled with two paths for outputfile and folder varibales, but I do not know if the error still present on Linux. I think that's something linked directly to the os.path.getsize(file_name), because if I remove the part related to the get_file_size operator in the last for cycle, everything works fine, but I don't get the size of elements.
I've Python 2.7.14.

Comment: I tried with a file `Strojniški` - it printed a line with the correct name and size, without issues.

Comment: At least is comfortable to know that the code "should" work, and the issue is probably on other subjects... Maybe it is related to Windows, I do not know. Thanks for your efforts! :)

Comment: It do not gives any problem even with "Strojniški načrti"? I've supposed that the problem was the special S character, but maybe it is the C, I do not know.

Comment: Right, here it still works with the name `Strojniški načrti`.

Comment: I've ran out of options... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I want to add that I've the same problem even with filenames that contains this symbol: ⚠️

This means probably that the problem is not related to specific characters, but to a lot of special characters.

Comment: Probably, the issue can be solved by this page

[link](https://superuser.com/questions/1097217/determine-and-change-filename-encoding-on-windows/1111543)

I will try later (I do not have at the moment the possibility to change parameters in Region Windows section) and I'll post if positive or negative result.